# Is it possible to have multiple domain names pointing to different urls on same webpage?

Tags: dns, server, subdomain, appdomain, domain-name

There is a webpage. Users have their own profiles there. I need to allow users to have a deep link to their profiles. The easiest way is to use my webpage domain + user name. www.mywebpage.com/user-x

The question is if it is possible to allow users to bind their own domains to their profile urls on my web page.

E.g.
www.user-x.com should point to www.mywebpage.com/user-x so that user can see the same page by navigating either to www.user-x.com or www.mywebpage.com/user-x

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve all "user name based subdomains" (hostnames, actually) to the same address by means of a "wildcard DNS-A record". That takes care that all requests to hostnames like "userxyz.yourdomain.dev" is resolved to the IP address of your http server. 
Then you can use "virtual mass hosting" or the combination of a "fallback host" and a manual rewrite rule on the server itself to translate such an incoming request to the profile "page". So either you have dynamic hosts defined inside your http server, or, easier, you have a "default" host all requests are served by. Inside that hosts configuration you put a rewrite rule that forwards the request to the "profile page" by taking the user name form the host name inside the request.

The same is possible for registerable domains, as you use in your example. but that would mean each user has to register a domain! If that is desired (why? it is expensive for nothing!), then each user also has to take care to set the correct DNS-entries for "his" domain. nothing you can help with, except for providing information (your servers IP address). If that is done, then the same configuration for your http server can be used as in the example using subdomains instead of domains.

My advice: stick with "subdomains", so the pattern "userxyz.yourdomain.dev". Much easier to handle and use for your users, you can take care of everything for your users.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that users can have their own domain names. Can you please provide urls to more info on that topic? I need to understand it better to be able to implement. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see what URLs may be of value here. Obviously you need to understand how DNS works and how to configure it. But such information is easily available on google. Apart from that: take a look at the rewriting guide for the http server you use and its host configuration. This obviously differs depending on which server software you use.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it is possible to have a domain name such as 'www.user-x.com` by means of virtual host setting on my server?

Comment: No, you can only take care that your server replies to requests for that host _if such requests are sent to your host_. But that does not mean that requests to some domain automatically arrive at your host. That is a question of the DNS settings for the registered domains. That has _nothing_ to do with your system, nothing you can help with, as already said above. You (your users) have to register each domain (takes money and time) and configure the correct DNS resolution for each such registered domain. Does not sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: BTW, to prevent confusion: `www.user-x.com` is _not_ a domain name. It is a "hostname", sometimes also called a "subdomain". The registrable domain name would be `user-x.com`. As said in the last sentence in my answer above: my advice clearly is to go with hostnames instead of domain names. That means only one single domain has to be registered and you yourself can take care of the subdomain names for your users.

Comment: There is a possibility to transfer domain name settings from the domain provider (company where once registers a domain name) to another web project (e.g. hosting or vps server admin panel). Would that make easier for users to manage their domain settings?

Comment: No, not at all. Each user would have to register a separate domain and configure it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90863/discussion-between-arkascha-and-user2814599).